# Task is cancelled only when ThrowIfCancellationRequested is called

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a task that is doing an infinite loop.

I have a CancellationToken that I pass both to the Task.Run call as to the actual ExecutePoll function.

I wait for a few seconds and Cancel the token.

There is one Continuation that should run when the task is cancelled.

Turns out this continuation only runs if I explicitly call **cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();**. If I only break out of the loop the task is always in the status: **RanToCompletion**

Can anyone share some light as to what I am getting wrong here?

**CODE:**

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TaskCancellationTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static CancellationTokenSource _pollProcessTokenSource;

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            InitPollingProcess();

            await Task.Delay(5000);

            Console.WriteLine("Cancelling loop");
            _pollProcessTokenSource.Cancel();
            Console.WriteLine("Loop cancelled");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void InitPollingProcess()
        {
            try
            {
                _pollProcessTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

                Task pollForListenerConfigs = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    await ExecutePoll(_pollProcessTokenSource.Token);
                },
                    _pollProcessTokenSource.Token);

                pollForListenerConfigs.ContinueWith(_ =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Poll process stopped!");
                }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);

                pollForListenerConfigs.ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Task status: {t.Status}");
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Poll process failed with Exception:\n {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        private static async Task ExecutePoll(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exit from poll loop!");
                    //cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // UNCOMMENT TO MAKE CONTINUATION RUN
                    break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Looping...");

                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, passing the cancelation token to the `Task.Run` only check the cancelation token when it starts and if already canceled immediately returns a canceled task.  Otherwise the only way the task will be canceled is if you throw in the code before it finishes.  Also there's not much point in putting an async call into `Task.Run` unless it happens to contain some CPU bound code.

Comment: You might find these three articles interesting: [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads), [Recommended patterns for CancellationToken](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/recommended-patterns-for-cancellationtoken/) and [A Tour of Task, Part 9: Delegate Tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong, it is well explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation):

> You can terminate the operation by using one of these options:
>
> - By simply returning from the delegate. In many scenarios this is sufficient; *however, a task instance that is canceled in this way
>   transitions to the TaskStatus.RanToCompletion state*, not to the
>   TaskStatus.Canceled state.
> - By throwing a OperationCanceledException and passing it the token on which cancellation was requested. The preferred way to do this is
>   to use the ThrowIfCancellationRequested method. A task that is
>   canceled in this way transitions to the Canceled state, which the
>   calling code can use to verify that the task responded to its
>   cancellation request.